# How to enable brotli compression on Android System Webview?

Tags: android, android-webview, brotli

I tested on Android Emulator with API level 30. I found that Chrome for Android supports brotli, however the Android System Webview doesn't support brotli by default.

For example, if I open the link https://stackoverflow.com on Chrome for Android, I can see following request header.

> accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br

If I open the same link on Webview Browser Tester, I will see following request header, which doesn't include **br**.

> accept-encoding: gzip, deflate

I am using the WebView version: 83.0.4103.106. How to enable brotli support on Android System Webview?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/android_webview/docs/developer-ui.md,
brotli is an experimental flag in the WebView settings, so you should enable this flag in your system setting

Comment: genewwww is this possible to enable brotli for every user and we can use it in release android appllication?